# jupyter notebook does not open in web page

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, importerror

I just done with downloading anaconda and tried to open jupyter notebook but I get import error, showing on comment like --> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: . please find the below attached.
[comment prompt - screen captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mPtQ.png)

it seems to be it is related to path.. please kindly help me out .. thanks.

Comment: did you install the 32 bit version? I guess you have a 64 bit processor and can go for the 64 bit version. The PATH seems fine as you can find `python`. Perhaps try installing the 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

Hey i will say you simple trick. Type in console

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

After finishing work

```
 conda config --set ssl_verify Yes
```

Note: Dont miss second step. Because web with no SSL is more vulnerable